# Link between entities with JPA

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, backend, h2

I'm creating a java web application, and for the backend, I use JPA and a h2 database.
I have for the moment one class called Secteur and one class called Bassin.
In my conception, one Secteur can have many Bassin, but one Bassin can have just one Secteur. Moreover it's not possible to create a Bassin if there is no Secteur already created (because one Bassin is already linked to a Secteur).

This is the Secteur class :

```
@Entity
public class Secteur {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    private String nom;
    ...
}
```

And this is the Bassin class :

```
@Entity
public class Bassin {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    private String nomBassin;
    private int tailleMax;
    private int tailleUtilise;
    private Date dernierNetoyage;
    private String etatBassin;
    private int idSecteur;
    ...
}
```

After a lot of research, I had seen that different annotation exist like @ManyToOne, @OneToMany, etc. But I don't know how to use them in order to resolve my problem.

1) Can you help me please ?

2)Moreover if I use these annotations can I remove "private int idSecteur" ?

Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: You may find this useful to read: https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-one-to-many
It will explain how to use the @OneToMany annotation and also how to set it up. I used it myself when first learning about linking entities.

Answer (score 0):

The `Secteur` entity mapping should be:

```
@Entity
public class Secteur {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    private String nom;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="secteur_id", nullable=false)
    private Bassin bassin;
}
```

The `bassin` entity mapping should be:

```
@Entity
public class Bassin {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    private String nomBassin;
    private int tailleMax;
    private int tailleUtilise;
    private Date dernierNetoyage;
    private String etatBassin;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="bassin")
    private Set<Secteur> secteurs;
}
```

Note that secteur_id in the annotation refers to the name of secteur id column in database.

I advise you to take a look to this more [complete reference](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-one-to-many)

Comment: Just to be complete, the @JoinColumn(nullable = false) is only used during DDL generation. If you work with the hbm2ddl parameter to validate or not using it, it won't trigger any exception is the value is null at insert time. To be sure I suggest you to validate manually your entity or use JSR303 annotation as @NotNull above the "bassin" definition. The response here contains somes mistakes too, the "ManyToOne" should not have a "mappedBy" attribute as the mapping is defined the "JoinColumns" and the "mappedBy" of the "OneToMany" is not correct, should be "bassin" instead of "cart"

Comment: bad copy/paste. Thanks for the hint

Comment: Thank you for your answers !

Comment: I have a problem in my Secteur class with @JoinColumn(name="secteur_id", nullable=false) when I implemented your answer.

I have this error :

Cannot resolve column 'secteur_id'

Do you know how to resolve it ?

Comment: As i added in the note above. secteur_id should contains the name of your real column name in database. Is that the case?

Comment: Yes, in the Bassin class I have a field called idSecteur and in my my database the name of the column ID_SECTEUR.
So I wrote
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="ID_SECTEUR", nullable=false)
    private Bassin2 bassins ;

but the error persists.

Comment: can you update the question and post your hibernate file. Did you associate your persistence.xml with data source ?